# How to build properly this query? Is this a proper MySql scheme?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this db:

```
* net_sales
account_id (pk)
date (pk)
amount

* refund
account_id (pk)
date (pk)
amount

* fees
account_id (pk)
date (pk)
amount

* adjustment_3rd_party
account_id (pk)
date (pk)
amount

* corporate_charges
account_id (pk)
date (pk)
amount
```

Although they share the same pk I separate then in case there are new variables to account for, which probably will, I don't need to keep adding columns to the table, instead I can create another table and just concatenate them.

This is what I'm doing:

```
SELECT net_sales.amount, refund.amount, fees.amount, adjustment_3rd_party.amount, corporate_charges.amount
FROM net_sales
LEFT JOIN refund ON (refund.date = net_sales.date AND refund.account_id = net_sales.account_id)
LEFT JOIN fees ON (fees.date = net_sales.date AND fees.account_id = net_sales.account_id)
LEFT JOIN adjustment_3rd_party ON (adjustment_3rd_party.date = net_sales.date AND adjustment_3rd_party.account_id = net_sales.account_id)
LEFT JOIN corporate_charges ON (corporate_charges.date = net_sales.date AND corporate_charges.account_id = net_sales.account_id)
WHERE net_sales.account_id = 40394 AND net_sales.date = '2016-01-01';
```

I'm doing something wrong? I'm getting a lot of duplicates and all of them have the same amount...

Thanks!

Comment: The joins in this code seem fine, but this is not the code your run as WHERE net_sales.account_id = 40394 AND net_sales.account_id = '2016-01-01' would return zero rows and the net_sales.account_id cannot be both. 
P.S.: Why is a refund always on the same date as the sale?

Comment: The tables are for transactions placed on that day, it doesn't mean the refunds were from sales of the day, but they were issued on that day, did I make any sense? So how should I build the query in order to pull correctly?

Comment: Please read the first part of my comment about this not being the query you execute as this query cannot return any rows at all.

Comment: Ohh I'm sorry I didn't fully understand what you comment. Got it... but is there a way to pull such a report with the table structure I have?

Comment: Switched to answer as I need more space to explain what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the problem is not in the query, but in your data.

If you have two refunds amounts and two fee amounts for one net_sales account_id and date combination, then this query will return four rows with unique combinations for each refund row with each fee row. In other words it can explode in the way you describe.

This means some of your tables contains duplicate rows, that is for this account_id and date combination they return more than one row.

In other words: the primary keys are not enforced.

Comment: Hi, thanks. That was the query I come up with... I tried on phpmyadmin and I got a lot of duplicates, and then I posted here for help...

Comment: Again: this query CANNOT RETURN ANY ROWS! net_sales.account_id cannot be both 40394 and '2016-01-01'. You used a different query.

Comment: Ohhhh! I apologize!!! I see what you mean!!!! Let me correct on my question. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Ok, I fixed, I must have messed it up cleaning the format to post here, I apologize.

Comment: My apology, it was a minor fix to your query, but it did unblock my thinking in a different direction as you can see. :)

Comment: No problem. No, unfortunately I don't have duplicates on the database...

Comment: Then you have two solution directions: use SELECT * FROM to return all the data and see which information is repeated all the time or change the LEFT JOIN's to INNER JOIN's and see if anythin changes. Probably wise to try both.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help the INNER JOIN and SELECT * helped me debugging! Thank you so much! I'll accept your answer

Comment: Sometimes both half the problem and half the solution are finding a way to debug. :)